# Laravel - Eloquent ORM Relationship Query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, orm, eloquent

I have 5 tables:

```
 1. news
 2. tags
 3. filters
 4. news_tag
 5. tag_filters
```

The tables structure are as follows:

**news**

```
id
title
description
```

**tags**

```
id
title
```

**filters**

```
id
title
```

**news_tag**

```
id
tag_id
news_id
```

**tag_filter**

```
id
tag_id
filter_id
```

Let's say for example my tables have the following records:

```
news: id = 1 title = News_1 Description = Details for News_1
tags: id = 1 title = PHP
filters: id = 1 title = PHP News
news_tag: id = 1 tag_id = 1 news_id = 1
tag_filter: id = 1 tag_id = 1 filter_id = 1
```

The relationships in my models are as follows:

**News model**

```
public function tags(){

    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag', 'news_tag');
}
```

**Tag model**

```
public function news(){

    return $this->belongsToMany('App\News', 'news_tag');
} 

public function filters(){

    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Filter', 'tag_filter');
}
```

**Filter model**

```
public function tags(){

    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag', 'tag_filter');
}
```

Let's say my route is as follows: `Route::get('news/filter/{filter_id}','NewsController@getNews');`

I want to retrieve all the news related to **tag_id 1** when I pass **filter_id 1** to my route. Anyone can help me how to do this in my controller?

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple way to do this, but you can use something like this:

```
News::select("news.*")
  ->join('tags'...)
  ->join('filters'...)
  ->where('filter_id',...)
  ->where('tag_id',...)
  ->get();
```

Note `select()` instruction. If you skip it, Laravel will load invalid fields into your `News` models. It's must-have when you do joins in Eloquent Builder.

If you want to eager load relations in this case, use `with()` method of the query builder.

Comment: Could you elaborate the join and where conditions for me please? The thing is that the tag_id is related to the news_id. So basically I need to get all the tag_ids which is related to the filter_id that I pass to my route and then look for all the news_ids related to those tag_ids.

Answer (score 0):

You can try some nested whereHas instead of join. I'm not sure about performance.

```
    $filterId = 1;
    News::whereHas('tags', function($q1) use ($filterId) {
        $q1->whereHas('filters', function($q2) use ($filterId) {
            $q2->where('id', '=', $filterId);
        });
    });
```

Comment: It [can be slow](http://www.fractalizer.ru/frpost_908/laravels-eloquenthas-and-eloquentwherehas-performance-problems/).